# Python websocket client raise 'sslv3 alert bad record mac' error when configure nginx with https

Tags: python, https, websocket

I use [websocket client library](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client) to communicate my websocket server build with `django channels` and `daphne` behind `nginx`.

When I add `https` configure to `nginx`, the `websocket client` can connect the server but raise error when send messge:

`[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_RECORD_MAC] sslv3 alert bad record mac (_ssl.c:2273)`

I try my best but I just can not find the solution. Follow the [websocket client library](https://github.com/websocket-client/websocket-client) readme, I add `sslopt` option to `disable ssl cert verification` and try other `ssl` option, but always get the `bad record mac` error.

Any suggestion and references will be great appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you cannot read write concurrently to a SSL socket because the SSL CTX will get corrupted due to inter leaved writes and reads.

Comment: @user855 Not the concurrency problem at least now.  I just use one process and log the send msg to double check.